# R: Findest nearest smaller value/date from another dataframe

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

Ratings:

```
CUSIP   Date       Rating
BAEU    01.01.2014  A+
BAEU    30.01.2015  A
BAEU    28.02.2017  BB
BAEU    28.03.2018  BB
CUOD    01.03.2010  BBB
CUOD    02.03.2012  BB
CUOD    03.03.2016  AA
CUOD    04.03.2018  C
BBAE    20.06.2009  A
BBAE    21.06.2012  A+
BBAE    22.11.2015  B-
BBAE    23.06.2016  BBB
```

Output:

```
Date        CUSIP
01.05.2014  BAEU
01.01.2015  BAEU
01.02.2015  BAEU
01.01.2017  BAEU
02.01.2017  BAEU
15.03.2018  BAEU
01.05.2010  CUOD
02.08.2012  CUOD
01.01.2016  CUOD
04.05.2018  CUOD
20.06.2010  BBAE
21.01.2012  BBAE
23.11.2015  BBAE
01.01.2016  BBAE
23.06.2016  BBAE
```

I'd like to add a column to the data frame "Output" that is called "Rating". This column comes from data frame "Ratings" and takes the rating, based on the CUSIP and the rating that is valid on that respective date.

The result should look as following:

Output_II (column Rating to be generated):

```
Date        CUSIP   Rating (to be generated, based on data frame Rating)
01.05.2014  BAEU    A+
01.01.2015  BAEU    A+
01.02.2015  BAEU    A
01.01.2017  BAEU    A
02.01.2017  BAEU    A
15.03.2018  BAEU    BB
01.05.2010  CUOD    BBB
02.08.2012  CUOD    BB
01.01.2016  CUOD    BB
04.05.2018  CUOD    C
20.06.2010  BBAE    A
21.01.2012  BBAE    A
23.11.2015  BBAE    B-
01.01.2016  BBAE    B-
23.06.2016  BBAE    BBB
```

I have already tried with dplyr and zoo. It looked something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
Output_II = Output %>% 
  group_by(cusip, date) %>% 
  mutate(...)
```

However, I did not find a way to finishing the code.

Comment: It's not evident in the data that your date column is a `Date` or `POSIXct` class. Is it currently a `character` column?

Comment: That's right. It's actually a Date (Format). I.e. "2009-01-30"

Comment: merge.xts should be able to work well for these things but I just spent 15 min pulling my hair (and I did the data camp course like 2 days ago :(). It seems it can only join by index, so you'd have to split both tables first, then convert to xts, then join, then reassemble the table, then reconvert is a data.frame if you want this layout with dates unsorted, not so pretty... I'll upvote a good xts solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could fully join the dataframes, arrange on CUSIP and Date, and use the na.locf() function from zoo to carry the last Rating observation forward to fill the NAs. Since you've arranged on CUSIP and Date, the missing Ratings will be replaced by the appropriate Rating observations. At last, you need to filter the resulting dataframe so that it only contains the rows from the original Output dataframe. A safe method for that last step could be a right_join with the original Output, which also assures Output is arranged in the same order as originally.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

Output %>% 
  full_join(Ratings) %>% 
  arrange(CUSIP, Date) %>% 
  mutate(Rating = na.locf(Rating)) %>% 
  right_join(Output)

         Date CUSIP Rating
1  2014-05-01  BAEU     A+
2  2015-01-01  BAEU     A+
3  2015-02-01  BAEU      A
4  2017-01-01  BAEU      A
5  2017-01-02  BAEU      A
6  2018-03-15  BAEU     BB
7  2010-05-01  CUOD    BBB
8  2012-08-02  CUOD     BB
9  2016-01-01  CUOD     BB
10 2018-05-04  CUOD      C
11 2010-06-20  BBAE      A
12 2012-01-21  BBAE      A
13 2015-11-23  BBAE     B-
14 2016-01-01  BBAE     B-
15 2016-06-23  BBAE    BBB
```

## DATA:

```
Ratings <- read.table(text = "CUSIP   Date       Rating
                      BAEU    01.01.2014  A+
                        BAEU    30.01.2015  A
                      BAEU    28.02.2017  BB
                      BAEU    28.03.2018  BB
                      CUOD    01.03.2010  BBB
                      CUOD    02.03.2012  BB
                      CUOD    03.03.2016  AA
                      CUOD    04.03.2018  C
                      BBAE    20.06.2009  A
                      BBAE    21.06.2012  A+
                        BBAE    22.11.2015  B-
                        BBAE    23.06.2016  BBB", h = T )

Output <- read.table(text = "Date        CUSIP
01.05.2014  BAEU
                     01.01.2015  BAEU
                     01.02.2015  BAEU
                     01.01.2017  BAEU
                     02.01.2017  BAEU
                     15.03.2018  BAEU
                     01.05.2010  CUOD
                     02.08.2012  CUOD
                     01.01.2016  CUOD
                     04.05.2018  CUOD
                     20.06.2010  BBAE
                     21.01.2012  BBAE
                     23.11.2015  BBAE
                     01.01.2016  BBAE
                     23.06.2016  BBAE", h = T)

Ratings$Date <- as.Date(Ratings$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")
Output$Date <- as.Date(Output$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

Based on comments, below code could be safer in case not all CUSIPS in Output have a Rating in Ratings from before the first CUSIP date in Output. Also, the data I used is slightly modified to show what happens:

```
Ratings <- read.table(text = "CUSIP   Date       Rating
                      BAEU    01.01.2014  A+
                        BAEU    30.01.2015  A
                      BAEU    28.02.2017  BB
                      BAEU    28.03.2018  BB
                      CUOD    01.03.2010  BBB
                      CUOD    02.03.2012  BB
                      CUOD    03.03.2016  AA
                      CUOD    04.03.2018  C
                      BBAE    20.06.2009  A
                      BBAE    21.06.2012  A+
                        BBAE    22.11.2015  B-
                        BBAE    23.06.2016  BBB
                      TEST 01.01.2018 AAA", h = T )

Output <- read.table(text = "Date        CUSIP
01.05.2014  BAEU
                     01.01.2015  BAEU
                     01.02.2015  BAEU
                     01.01.2017  BAEU
                     02.01.2017  BAEU
                     15.03.2018  BAEU
                     01.05.2010  CUOD
                     02.08.2012  CUOD
                     01.01.2016  CUOD
                     04.05.2018  CUOD
                     20.06.2010  BBAE
                     21.01.2012  BBAE
                     23.11.2015  BBAE
                     01.01.2016  BBAE
                     23.06.2016  BBAE
                     01.01.2017 TEST
                     01.01.2019 TEST", h = T)

Ratings$Date <- as.Date(Ratings$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")
Output$Date <- as.Date(Output$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)


Output %>% 
  full_join(Ratings) %>% 
  arrange(CUSIP, Date) %>% 
  group_by(CUSIP) %>% 
  mutate(Rating = na.locf(Rating, na.rm = F)) %>% 
  right_join(Output)


         Date  CUSIP Rating
       <date> <fctr> <fctr>
 1 2014-05-01   BAEU     A+
 2 2015-01-01   BAEU     A+
 3 2015-02-01   BAEU      A
 4 2017-01-01   BAEU      A
 5 2017-01-02   BAEU      A
 6 2018-03-15   BAEU     BB
 7 2010-05-01   CUOD    BBB
 8 2012-08-02   CUOD     BB
 9 2016-01-01   CUOD     BB
10 2018-05-04   CUOD      C
11 2010-06-20   BBAE      A
12 2012-01-21   BBAE      A
13 2015-11-23   BBAE     B-
14 2016-01-01   BBAE     B-
15 2016-06-23   BBAE    BBB
16 2017-01-01   TEST   <NA>
17 2019-01-01   TEST    AAA
```

Comment: Nice method, using `zoo::na.locf` on a full join. +1

Comment: you should really add a group_by, this is not safe as it is now

Comment: What I meant is that, if you look at your output just after the `arrange` call, you're "lucky" that you have a value from first df as a first rating value for each group, else your `na.locf` would go too far and fill values that should stay NAs (still upvoted :) )

Comment: It's very possible that by design the dates from first df expand further so there won't be issues, but using `na.locf` without isolating the groups from each other is dangerous. So I would have added a `group_by(CUSIP)` between `arrange` and `mutate`

Comment: I agree to that, surely, and you are right a group_by() function could solve this potential hazard. :)

Comment: BTW, in that case you need to add na.rm = F in the na.locf function. I have added it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you Len for your suggestion. The problem is that not all of the CUSIPs in data.frame "Ratings" are used in data.frame "Output". I guess that leads to the result/problem that I now have more rows in the final data.frame "Output_II" than in the "original" data.frame "Output". Is there a way to only add the ratings for those CUIPS that are part of data.frame "Output"?

Comment: If you end with `%>% right_join(Output)` that should not be happening. If it does, please provide some data where that happens.

Comment: Is the problem probably that not all the CUSIPs from data.frame Output are included in the data.frame "Ratings"? But this can't be my problem either...

Comment: no, because with the `right_join()` you filter on only the rows that were in Output

Comment: hi len. I have found the problem, however I am struggling in finding a solution. In my dataframe Output, I have some lines (rows) that have the same date. And then the code somehow does not work anymore. Would you mind looking again into the code?

Comment: Do you have same dates for different CUSIPs or within the same CUSIPs?

Comment: I have same dates for the same CUSIP.

Comment: I don´t see why it would not be working in that case without sample data. But you might consider to start the code with: `Output %>%   group_by(Date, CUSIP) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%` and then continue with the `full_join`

Comment: let's say we change in your sample data as following: Output <- read.table(text = "Date        CUSIP
01.05.2014  BAEU
                     01.01.2015  BAEU
                     01.01.2015  BAEU
                     01.01.2015  BAEU
                     02.01.2017  BAEU
                     15.03.2018  BAEU
                     01.05.2010  CUOD
                     01.05.2010  CUOD
                     01.01.2016  CUOD
                     04.05.2018  CUOD
                     01.01.2019 TEST", h = T). In that case I have to much rows in the Output_II...

Comment: I see. That is caused by the final `right_join`. Do you have any other important variables in Output? Otherwise I'd suggest to remove the duplicate rows from Output before running this operation.

Comment: In case you do have other important variables in Output, please create a temporary Output2 before hand like this: `Output2 <- Output %>% 
  group_by(Date, CUSIP) %>% 
  slice(1)`  Then you can run in the code in my answer again, with one slight modification: start with `Output2` instead of `Output`

Comment: Or just do it in 1 chain like I suggest in above comments: `Output %>% 
  group_by(Date, CUSIP) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  full_join(Ratings) %>% 
  arrange(CUSIP, Date) %>% 
  group_by(CUSIP) %>% 
  mutate(Rating = na.locf(Rating, na.rm = F)) %>% 
  right_join(Output)
`

Comment: Wow, this is it Len!! I appreciate your support. For all that have the same problem, this code from Len works greatly: Output %>% group_by(Date, CUSIP) %>% slice(1) %>% full_join(Ratings) %>% arrange(CUSIP, Date) %>% group_by(CUSIP) %>% mutate(Rating = na.locf(Rating, na.rm = F)) %>% right_join(Output)